# Language parameter in .htaccess not correctly mapped

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to rewrite this url:

> www.answerme.be/index.php?language=nl

**to**

> www.answerme.be/nl

I've already done some research and I am using the tool from *generateit.net*.

The expression that I am using is the following:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?language=$1 [L]
```

This should work? I am getting a `500 internal server` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting 500 due to infinite looping. Fix it by using better regex for 2 character language in URI:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ /index.php?language=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your languages are limited, you can specify them to escape this error

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(nl|en|fr)$ index.php?language=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use lang param also on uppercase, use this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})$ index.php?language=$1 [L]
```

It works perfect for me